# How to get unicode string from C++ to C# using PInvoke

Tags: c#, string, pinvoke, unicode-string

I have the following signature of a C++ method. The last argument should return the device name as a 2 byte unicode string.

```
int GetDeviceIdentifier(DWORD deviceIndex, WCHAR** ppDeviceName);
```

I wrapped into C# with the following signature. It works but the string that I get is strange. Am I doing something wrong?

```
[DllImportAttribute("StclDevices.dll", EntryPoint = "GetDeviceIdentifier", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetDeviceIdentifier(uint deviceIndex, StringBuilder ppDeviceName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a `StringBuilder` parameter would match a C++ parameter of type `WCHAR*`. In that case the memory would be allocated by the C# code by setting the capacity of the string builder object.

For your function it would appear that the memory is allocated by the C++ code. Hence the double pointer. So you would need this:

```
[DllImportAttribute("StclDevices.dll", 
    CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetDeviceIdentifier(
    uint deviceIndex, 
    out IntPtr ppDeviceName
);
```

You call it like this:

```
IntPtr ppDeviceName;
int retval = GetDeviceIdentifier(deviceIndex, out ppDeviceName);
string DeviceName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ppDeviceName);
```

Comment: Now I know why I don't like C++. All these pointers ... Thanks for your help. This worked absolutely fine. I used a StringBuilder with a capacity of 128 before which resulted in a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DllImportAttribute("StclDevices.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern Int32 GetDeviceIdentifier([In] UInt32 deviceIndex, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr), Out] out String ppDeviceName);

String ppDeviceName;
NativeMethods.GetDeviceIdentifier(i, out ppDeviceName);
```

If you want to stick on StringBuilder, use this instead:

```
[DllImportAttribute("StclDevices.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern Int32 GetDeviceIdentifier([In] UInt32 deviceIndex, [In, Out] StringBuilder ppDeviceName);

StringBuilder ppDeviceName = new StringBuilder(255);
NativeMethods.GetDeviceIdentifier(i, ppDeviceName);
```

Comment: Variant 1 is going to lead to `CoTaskMemFree` being called on the pointer behind `ppDeviceName`. Variant 2 is incorrect because it's a double pointer in the C++ code. And `SetLastError` should not be `true` here. That's for Win32 API functions.