# pinvoke returning ascii char array to c#

Tags: c#, c, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I am writing an application in c# that use a dll i wrote in c using pinvoke.
Here is the code of the dll:

```
 __declspec(dllexport) char** foo()
    {
        int i;
        char arr[5]="omer";
        char **str_arr=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        str_arr[0]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
        strcpy(str_arr[0],arr);
        return str_arr;
    }
```

Here is the code in c#:

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("gg.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static unsafe extern char** foo();
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int  [] arr;
      int i;
    char [] char_arr={'o','m','e','r'};
      string[] string_arr=new string [1];
      char** str_arr;
        str_arr=foo();
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
           char_arr[i]=str_arr[0][i];
        }
        string_arr[0] = new string(st);
        free(*str_arr);
       free(str_arr);
    }
}
```

Now when the pointer returns, the content of the first array of chars is gibberish(chinese characters) instead of "omer" why is that?

I thought it might be because char array in c# might use unicode encoding but when i tested the value of the content in char_arr before changing it after the function foo is called, it represented the letters in ASCII

Comment: Pretty basic problems.  A *char* in C# is not a match for a char in C.  The C# version takes 2 bytes, the closest match for the C variety is *byte*.  Your free() call is obviously flawed, you had *two* malloc() calls in your C code, that requires two free() calls to match.  The odds that they use the same memory allocator are low.

Comment: thank you and i check my free call isn't flawed i check and the pointer in c# have the same address as the one allocated in c

Comment: This code is all wrong. This is not how to do it. Would you like us to help show you how to do it the right way, or are you already set fair?

Comment: @David Heffernan i would like you to show me the right way i really wonder what i did wrong? and the code might be ugly and it's just because it's just a little snippet i wrote to try transferring string from c to c#. my code would be much more readable and not using good code practices when i will integrate it to my application

Comment: Use SysAllocString to return a BSTR

Comment: thank you but can you explain what's wrong with my code except that c# use a word to represent characters and except memory leaks? i want to know why your method is better

Comment: You have to use nasty unsafe code and export a deallocator.

Comment: can you give a code example for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `C` code is working with single-byte characters while your `C#` code is expecting 16-bit double-byte characters.

Have a look at a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342140/how-to-get-unicode-string-from-c-to-c-sharp-using-pinvoke).